# django oscar wrong order while loading models of forked apps

Tags: django, models, django-oscar

I have a strange problem where one of the forked apps model is loaded after the one from oscar instead other forked apps are loaded in the correct order; this is causing a RuntimeError because our app tries to register a model that is already registered.

I have checked the get_core_apps() return value and the oscar model is overridden by our custom UserAddress model.

does AbstractUserAddress require some additional work or different procedure?

for all our cusom models we have followed this [guide](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.3/howto/how_to_customise_models.html) but only the custom UserAddress has problems at load time.

Comment: Have you made sure that the line `from oscar.apps.address.models import * ` is at the end of your forked `models.py`, and not at the beginning?

Comment: Yes checked and checked millions of times :)